# How can I prevent background scrolling in IOs?

Tags: javascript, ios, css, mobile, scroll

I need to disable scrolling for the `div # scrolling-disabled` on mobile browsers for both `iOS` and `Android` devices. I can't use the `position: fixed;` trick or it will broke my layout. So I'm handling the `touchmove` event to prevent the default action. The code below works but only if you drag your finger **directly** in the `div # scrolling-disabled` element. If you drag your finger in the `div # window` element or even in the `div # scrolling-enabled` IOs **will still scroll the element in the background**, in this case, `div # scrolling-disabled`.

```js
document.querySelector('#scroll-disabled').addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) { event.preventDefault(); });
```

```css
#window
{
display: block;
position: fixed;
margin: 30px;
z-index: 999;
background-color: #fff;
border: 1px solid red;
}

#scroll-enabled
{
height: 100px;
overflow: auto;
border: 1px solid red;
margin: 10px;
}

#scroll-disabled
{

}

p
{
margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<div id="window">
<p><b>Scrolling should be disabled for the DIV element in the background (#scroll-disabled), but should still be possible in the DIV element below (#scroll-enabled).</b></p>
<div id="scroll-enabled">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed laoreet quam non mi sagittis hendrerit. Nulla tristique eget nibh et finibus. Pellentesque placerat hendrerit enim eu convallis. Sed posuere dolor ac est finibus, non egestas lacus pellentesque. Mauris dictum nibh id nisi venenatis dictum. Etiam sit amet congue neque. Cras molestie nulla faucibus ante molestie, a suscipit ligula sagittis. Sed condimentum orci id lacus cursus dignissim. Curabitur et urna erat. Integer sem augue, rhoncus ac venenatis a, viverra sed enim. Nullam fermentum auctor risus nec congue. Sed leo libero, lobortis vitae nisi in, placerat rutrum nisl. Nullam dapibus purus nec nisl aliquet, vel auctor nulla consequat.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed laoreet quam non mi sagittis hendrerit. Nulla tristique eget nibh et finibus. Pellentesque placerat hendrerit enim eu convallis. Sed posuere dolor ac est finibus, non egestas lacus pellentesque. Mauris dictum nibh id nisi venenatis dictum. Etiam sit amet congue neque. Cras molestie nulla faucibus ante molestie, a suscipit ligula sagittis. Sed condimentum orci id lacus cursus dignissim. Curabitur et urna erat. Integer sem augue, rhoncus ac venenatis a, viverra sed enim. Nullam fermentum auctor risus nec congue. Sed leo libero, lobortis vitae nisi in, placerat rutrum nisl. Nullam dapibus purus nec nisl aliquet, vel auctor nulla consequat.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed laoreet quam non mi sagittis hendrerit. Nulla tristique eget nibh et finibus. Pellentesque placerat hendrerit enim eu convallis. Sed posuere dolor ac est finibus, non egestas lacus pellentesque. Mauris dictum nibh id nisi venenatis dictum. Etiam sit amet congue neque. Cras molestie nulla faucibus ante molestie, a suscipit ligula sagittis. Sed condimentum orci id lacus cursus dignissim. Curabitur et urna erat. Integer sem augue, rhoncus ac venenatis a, viverra sed enim. Nullam fermentum auctor risus nec congue. Sed leo libero, lobortis vitae nisi in, placerat rutrum nisl. Nullam dapibus purus nec nisl aliquet, vel auctor nulla consequat.</p>
</div>
</div>

<div id="scroll-disabled">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed laoreet quam non mi sagittis hendrerit. Nulla tristique eget nibh et finibus. Pellentesque placerat hendrerit enim eu convallis. Sed posuere dolor ac est finibus, non egestas lacus pellentesque. Mauris dictum nibh id nisi venenatis dictum. Etiam sit amet congue neque. Cras molestie nulla faucibus ante molestie, a suscipit ligula sagittis. Sed condimentum orci id lacus cursus dignissim. Curabitur et urna erat. Integer sem augue, rhoncus ac venenatis a, viverra sed enim. Nullam fermentum auctor risus nec congue. Sed leo libero, lobortis vitae nisi in, placerat rutrum nisl. Nullam dapibus purus nec nisl aliquet, vel auctor nulla consequat.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed laoreet quam non mi sagittis hendrerit. Nulla tristique eget nibh et finibus. Pellentesque placerat hendrerit enim eu convallis. Sed posuere dolor ac est finibus, non egestas lacus pellentesque. Mauris dictum nibh id nisi venenatis dictum. Etiam sit amet congue neque. Cras molestie nulla faucibus ante molestie, a suscipit ligula sagittis. Sed condimentum orci id lacus cursus dignissim. Curabitur et urna erat. Integer sem augue, rhoncus ac venenatis a, viverra sed enim. Nullam fermentum auctor risus nec congue. Sed leo libero, lobortis vitae nisi in, placerat rutrum nisl. Nullam dapibus purus nec nisl aliquet, vel auctor nulla consequat.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed laoreet quam non mi sagittis hendrerit. Nulla tristique eget nibh et finibus. Pellentesque placerat hendrerit enim eu convallis. Sed posuere dolor ac est finibus, non egestas lacus pellentesque. Mauris dictum nibh id nisi venenatis dictum. Etiam sit amet congue neque. Cras molestie nulla faucibus ante molestie, a suscipit ligula sagittis. Sed condimentum orci id lacus cursus dignissim. Curabitur et urna erat. Integer sem augue, rhoncus ac venenatis a, viverra sed enim. Nullam fermentum auctor risus nec congue. Sed leo libero, lobortis vitae nisi in, placerat rutrum nisl. Nullam dapibus purus nec nisl aliquet, vel auctor nulla consequat.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed laoreet quam non mi sagittis hendrerit. Nulla tristique eget nibh et finibus. Pellentesque placerat hendrerit enim eu convallis. Sed posuere dolor ac est finibus, non egestas lacus pellentesque. Mauris dictum nibh id nisi venenatis dictum. Etiam sit amet congue neque. Cras molestie nulla faucibus ante molestie, a suscipit ligula sagittis. Sed condimentum orci id lacus cursus dignissim. Curabitur et urna erat. Integer sem augue, rhoncus ac venenatis a, viverra sed enim. Nullam fermentum auctor risus nec congue. Sed leo libero, lobortis vitae nisi in, placerat rutrum nisl. Nullam dapibus purus nec nisl aliquet, vel auctor nulla consequat.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed laoreet quam non mi sagittis hendrerit. Nulla tristique eget nibh et finibus. Pellentesque placerat hendrerit enim eu convallis. Sed posuere dolor ac est finibus, non egestas lacus pellentesque. Mauris dictum nibh id nisi venenatis dictum. Etiam sit amet congue neque. Cras molestie nulla faucibus ante molestie, a suscipit ligula sagittis. Sed condimentum orci id lacus cursus dignissim. Curabitur et urna erat. Integer sem augue, rhoncus ac venenatis a, viverra sed enim. Nullam fermentum auctor risus nec congue. Sed leo libero, lobortis vitae nisi in, placerat rutrum nisl. Nullam dapibus purus nec nisl aliquet, vel auctor nulla consequat.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed laoreet quam non mi sagittis hendrerit. Nulla tristique eget nibh et finibus. Pellentesque placerat hendrerit enim eu convallis. Sed posuere dolor ac est finibus, non egestas lacus pellentesque. Mauris dictum nibh id nisi venenatis dictum. Etiam sit amet congue neque. Cras molestie nulla faucibus ante molestie, a suscipit ligula sagittis. Sed condimentum orci id lacus cursus dignissim. Curabitur et urna erat. Integer sem augue, rhoncus ac venenatis a, viverra sed enim. Nullam fermentum auctor risus nec congue. Sed leo libero, lobortis vitae nisi in, placerat rutrum nisl. Nullam dapibus purus nec nisl aliquet, vel auctor nulla consequat.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed laoreet quam non mi sagittis hendrerit. Nulla tristique eget nibh et finibus. Pellentesque placerat hendrerit enim eu convallis. Sed posuere dolor ac est finibus, non egestas lacus pellentesque. Mauris dictum nibh id nisi venenatis dictum. Etiam sit amet congue neque. Cras molestie nulla faucibus ante molestie, a suscipit ligula sagittis. Sed condimentum orci id lacus cursus dignissim. Curabitur et urna erat. Integer sem augue, rhoncus ac venenatis a, viverra sed enim. Nullam fermentum auctor risus nec congue. Sed leo libero, lobortis vitae nisi in, placerat rutrum nisl. Nullam dapibus purus nec nisl aliquet, vel auctor nulla consequat.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed laoreet quam non mi sagittis hendrerit. Nulla tristique eget nibh et finibus. Pellentesque placerat hendrerit enim eu convallis. Sed posuere dolor ac est finibus, non egestas lacus pellentesque. Mauris dictum nibh id nisi venenatis dictum. Etiam sit amet congue neque. Cras molestie nulla faucibus ante molestie, a suscipit ligula sagittis. Sed condimentum orci id lacus cursus dignissim. Curabitur et urna erat. Integer sem augue, rhoncus ac venenatis a, viverra sed enim. Nullam fermentum auctor risus nec congue. Sed leo libero, lobortis vitae nisi in, placerat rutrum nisl. Nullam dapibus purus nec nisl aliquet, vel auctor nulla consequat.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed laoreet quam non mi sagittis hendrerit. Nulla tristique eget nibh et finibus. Pellentesque placerat hendrerit enim eu convallis. Sed posuere dolor ac est finibus, non egestas lacus pellentesque. Mauris dictum nibh id nisi venenatis dictum. Etiam sit amet congue neque. Cras molestie nulla faucibus ante molestie, a suscipit ligula sagittis. Sed condimentum orci id lacus cursus dignissim. Curabitur et urna erat. Integer sem augue, rhoncus ac venenatis a, viverra sed enim. Nullam fermentum auctor risus nec congue. Sed leo libero, lobortis vitae nisi in, placerat rutrum nisl. Nullam dapibus purus nec nisl aliquet, vel auctor nulla consequat.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed laoreet quam non mi sagittis hendrerit. Nulla tristique eget nibh et finibus. Pellentesque placerat hendrerit enim eu convallis. Sed posuere dolor ac est finibus, non egestas lacus pellentesque. Mauris dictum nibh id nisi venenatis dictum. Etiam sit amet congue neque. Cras molestie nulla faucibus ante molestie, a suscipit ligula sagittis. Sed condimentum orci id lacus cursus dignissim. Curabitur et urna erat. Integer sem augue, rhoncus ac venenatis a, viverra sed enim. Nullam fermentum auctor risus nec congue. Sed leo libero, lobortis vitae nisi in, placerat rutrum nisl. Nullam dapibus purus nec nisl aliquet, vel auctor nulla consequat.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed laoreet quam non mi sagittis hendrerit. Nulla tristique eget nibh et finibus. Pellentesque placerat hendrerit enim eu convallis. Sed posuere dolor ac est finibus, non egestas lacus pellentesque. Mauris dictum nibh id nisi venenatis dictum. Etiam sit amet congue neque. Cras molestie nulla faucibus ante molestie, a suscipit ligula sagittis. Sed condimentum orci id lacus cursus dignissim. Curabitur et urna erat. Integer sem augue, rhoncus ac venenatis a, viverra sed enim. Nullam fermentum auctor risus nec congue. Sed leo libero, lobortis vitae nisi in, placerat rutrum nisl. Nullam dapibus purus nec nisl aliquet, vel auctor nulla consequat.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed laoreet quam non mi sagittis hendrerit. Nulla tristique eget nibh et finibus. Pellentesque placerat hendrerit enim eu convallis. Sed posuere dolor ac est finibus, non egestas lacus pellentesque. Mauris dictum nibh id nisi venenatis dictum. Etiam sit amet congue neque. Cras molestie nulla faucibus ante molestie, a suscipit ligula sagittis. Sed condimentum orci id lacus cursus dignissim. Curabitur et urna erat. Integer sem augue, rhoncus ac venenatis a, viverra sed enim. Nullam fermentum auctor risus nec congue. Sed leo libero, lobortis vitae nisi in, placerat rutrum nisl. Nullam dapibus purus nec nisl aliquet, vel auctor nulla consequat.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed laoreet quam non mi sagittis hendrerit. Nulla tristique eget nibh et finibus. Pellentesque placerat hendrerit enim eu convallis. Sed posuere dolor ac est finibus, non egestas lacus pellentesque. Mauris dictum nibh id nisi venenatis dictum. Etiam sit amet congue neque. Cras molestie nulla faucibus ante molestie, a suscipit ligula sagittis. Sed condimentum orci id lacus cursus dignissim. Curabitur et urna erat. Integer sem augue, rhoncus ac venenatis a, viverra sed enim. Nullam fermentum auctor risus nec congue. Sed leo libero, lobortis vitae nisi in, placerat rutrum nisl. Nullam dapibus purus nec nisl aliquet, vel auctor nulla consequat.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed laoreet quam non mi sagittis hendrerit. Nulla tristique eget nibh et finibus. Pellentesque placerat hendrerit enim eu convallis. Sed posuere dolor ac est finibus, non egestas lacus pellentesque. Mauris dictum nibh id nisi venenatis dictum. Etiam sit amet congue neque. Cras molestie nulla faucibus ante molestie, a suscipit ligula sagittis. Sed condimentum orci id lacus cursus dignissim. Curabitur et urna erat. Integer sem augue, rhoncus ac venenatis a, viverra sed enim. Nullam fermentum auctor risus nec congue. Sed leo libero, lobortis vitae nisi in, placerat rutrum nisl. Nullam dapibus purus nec nisl aliquet, vel auctor nulla consequat.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed laoreet quam non mi sagittis hendrerit. Nulla tristique eget nibh et finibus. Pellentesque placerat hendrerit enim eu convallis. Sed posuere dolor ac est finibus, non egestas lacus pellentesque. Mauris dictum nibh id nisi venenatis dictum. Etiam sit amet congue neque. Cras molestie nulla faucibus ante molestie, a suscipit ligula sagittis. Sed condimentum orci id lacus cursus dignissim. Curabitur et urna erat. Integer sem augue, rhoncus ac venenatis a, viverra sed enim. Nullam fermentum auctor risus nec congue. Sed leo libero, lobortis vitae nisi in, placerat rutrum nisl. Nullam dapibus purus nec nisl aliquet, vel auctor nulla consequat.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed laoreet quam non mi sagittis hendrerit. Nulla tristique eget nibh et finibus. Pellentesque placerat hendrerit enim eu convallis. Sed posuere dolor ac est finibus, non egestas lacus pellentesque. Mauris dictum nibh id nisi venenatis dictum. Etiam sit amet congue neque. Cras molestie nulla faucibus ante molestie, a suscipit ligula sagittis. Sed condimentum orci id lacus cursus dignissim. Curabitur et urna erat. Integer sem augue, rhoncus ac venenatis a, viverra sed enim. Nullam fermentum auctor risus nec congue. Sed leo libero, lobortis vitae nisi in, placerat rutrum nisl. Nullam dapibus purus nec nisl aliquet, vel auctor nulla consequat.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed laoreet quam non mi sagittis hendrerit. Nulla tristique eget nibh et finibus. Pellentesque placerat hendrerit enim eu convallis. Sed posuere dolor ac est finibus, non egestas lacus pellentesque. Mauris dictum nibh id nisi venenatis dictum. Etiam sit amet congue neque. Cras molestie nulla faucibus ante molestie, a suscipit ligula sagittis. Sed condimentum orci id lacus cursus dignissim. Curabitur et urna erat. Integer sem augue, rhoncus ac venenatis a, viverra sed enim. Nullam fermentum auctor risus nec congue. Sed leo libero, lobortis vitae nisi in, placerat rutrum nisl. Nullam dapibus purus nec nisl aliquet, vel auctor nulla consequat.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed laoreet quam non mi sagittis hendrerit. Nulla tristique eget nibh et finibus. Pellentesque placerat hendrerit enim eu convallis. Sed posuere dolor ac est finibus, non egestas lacus pellentesque. Mauris dictum nibh id nisi venenatis dictum. Etiam sit amet congue neque. Cras molestie nulla faucibus ante molestie, a suscipit ligula sagittis. Sed condimentum orci id lacus cursus dignissim. Curabitur et urna erat. Integer sem augue, rhoncus ac venenatis a, viverra sed enim. Nullam fermentum auctor risus nec congue. Sed leo libero, lobortis vitae nisi in, placerat rutrum nisl. Nullam dapibus purus nec nisl aliquet, vel auctor nulla consequat.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed laoreet quam non mi sagittis hendrerit. Nulla tristique eget nibh et finibus. Pellentesque placerat hendrerit enim eu convallis. Sed posuere dolor ac est finibus, non egestas lacus pellentesque. Mauris dictum nibh id nisi venenatis dictum. Etiam sit amet congue neque. Cras molestie nulla faucibus ante molestie, a suscipit ligula sagittis. Sed condimentum orci id lacus cursus dignissim. Curabitur et urna erat. Integer sem augue, rhoncus ac venenatis a, viverra sed enim. Nullam fermentum auctor risus nec congue. Sed leo libero, lobortis vitae nisi in, placerat rutrum nisl. Nullam dapibus purus nec nisl aliquet, vel auctor nulla consequat.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed laoreet quam non mi sagittis hendrerit. Nulla tristique eget nibh et finibus. Pellentesque placerat hendrerit enim eu convallis. Sed posuere dolor ac est finibus, non egestas lacus pellentesque. Mauris dictum nibh id nisi venenatis dictum. Etiam sit amet congue neque. Cras molestie nulla faucibus ante molestie, a suscipit ligula sagittis. Sed condimentum orci id lacus cursus dignissim. Curabitur et urna erat. Integer sem augue, rhoncus ac venenatis a, viverra sed enim. Nullam fermentum auctor risus nec congue. Sed leo libero, lobortis vitae nisi in, placerat rutrum nisl. Nullam dapibus purus nec nisl aliquet, vel auctor nulla consequat.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed laoreet quam non mi sagittis hendrerit. Nulla tristique eget nibh et finibus. Pellentesque placerat hendrerit enim eu convallis. Sed posuere dolor ac est finibus, non egestas lacus pellentesque. Mauris dictum nibh id nisi venenatis dictum. Etiam sit amet congue neque. Cras molestie nulla faucibus ante molestie, a suscipit ligula sagittis. Sed condimentum orci id lacus cursus dignissim. Curabitur et urna erat. Integer sem augue, rhoncus ac venenatis a, viverra sed enim. Nullam fermentum auctor risus nec congue. Sed leo libero, lobortis vitae nisi in, placerat rutrum nisl. Nullam dapibus purus nec nisl aliquet, vel auctor nulla consequat.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed laoreet quam non mi sagittis hendrerit. Nulla tristique eget nibh et finibus. Pellentesque placerat hendrerit enim eu convallis. Sed posuere dolor ac est finibus, non egestas lacus pellentesque. Mauris dictum nibh id nisi venenatis dictum. Etiam sit amet congue neque. Cras molestie nulla faucibus ante molestie, a suscipit ligula sagittis. Sed condimentum orci id lacus cursus dignissim. Curabitur et urna erat. Integer sem augue, rhoncus ac venenatis a, viverra sed enim. Nullam fermentum auctor risus nec congue. Sed leo libero, lobortis vitae nisi in, placerat rutrum nisl. Nullam dapibus purus nec nisl aliquet, vel auctor nulla consequat.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed laoreet quam non mi sagittis hendrerit. Nulla tristique eget nibh et finibus. Pellentesque placerat hendrerit enim eu convallis. Sed posuere dolor ac est finibus, non egestas lacus pellentesque. Mauris dictum nibh id nisi venenatis dictum. Etiam sit amet congue neque. Cras molestie nulla faucibus ante molestie, a suscipit ligula sagittis. Sed condimentum orci id lacus cursus dignissim. Curabitur et urna erat. Integer sem augue, rhoncus ac venenatis a, viverra sed enim. Nullam fermentum auctor risus nec congue. Sed leo libero, lobortis vitae nisi in, placerat rutrum nisl. Nullam dapibus purus nec nisl aliquet, vel auctor nulla consequat.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed laoreet quam non mi sagittis hendrerit. Nulla tristique eget nibh et finibus. Pellentesque placerat hendrerit enim eu convallis. Sed posuere dolor ac est finibus, non egestas lacus pellentesque. Mauris dictum nibh id nisi venenatis dictum. Etiam sit amet congue neque. Cras molestie nulla faucibus ante molestie, a suscipit ligula sagittis. Sed condimentum orci id lacus cursus dignissim. Curabitur et urna erat. Integer sem augue, rhoncus ac venenatis a, viverra sed enim. Nullam fermentum auctor risus nec congue. Sed leo libero, lobortis vitae nisi in, placerat rutrum nisl. Nullam dapibus purus nec nisl aliquet, vel auctor nulla consequat.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/56z3aorc/2/

And direct link to results if you wanna try on mobile: https://jsfiddle.net/56z3aorc/2/show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution myself.

1. Disable scrolling on the body or in the element you want by using `event.preventDefault();` on a `touchmove` event listener.
2. After doing that, you can allow scrolling on the element you need by using `event.stopPropagation();` on a `touchmove` event listener.
3. If you need to keep IOs from scrolling the elements in the background of the scrollable element (after it finnished it own scrolling) just do `event.stopPropagation();` first and then (if the element is full scrolled) do `event.preventDefault();`.

I hope it helps other people having the same issue I was.